# Why isn't this Wordpress query sorting properly

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom `post_type` called `special_listing` which contains a custom field called `listing_index`. A `special_listing` with a `listing_index` of 20, should appear before one with an index of 15, then 10, and so on. However this doesn't appear to be working and listings appear in whatever order they choose.

I'm not a PHP or Wordpress guy, I mainly deal with ASP.Net and C# so this is a bit confusing for me. Is there some simple mistake I'm making?

Function:

```
// Get the first $count listings with the highest indices for a given $region_slug:
function get_listings($region_slug, $count) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'special_listing',
        'meta_key' => 'listing_region_slug',
        'meta_value' => $region_slug
    );
    $posts = get_posts($args);

    sort_array_on_field($posts, 'listing_index', 'DESC');
    truncate_array($posts, $count);
    return $posts;
}
```

View:

```
<?php
    $listings = get_listings(get_microsite_slug() . '-microsite-home-featured', 4);
    $i = 0;
    if (sizeof($listings) > 0) : while ($i < sizeof($listings)) : $listing = $listings[$i]; // Loop and set current listing
    ?>
    <section>
        <a href="<?php echo $listing->destination; ?>">
            <h3><?php echo $listing->post_title; ?></h3>
            <p><?php echo $listing->post_content; ?></p>
        </a>
    </section>
    <?php $i++; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

My attempt:

I don't know how to return the `listing_index` value

```
function get_sorted_listings($region_slug, $count){
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'kodakalaris_listing',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array (
                'key' => 'listing_region_slug',
                'value' => $region_slug
            ),
            array (
                'key' => 'listing_index',
                'value' => ''
            ),
            orderby: 'listing_index',
            order: 'DESC'
        )
    );
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    truncate_array($posts, $count);
    return $posts;
}
```

**Update**

Trying a new way and it now pulls the content in by the published date. Still not ordering by `listing_index`, but at least it's not completely random either. I began looking to [meta_query](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/). Won't this only return a result with a single value? I've also tried out [this other SO answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15477/custom-query-with-orderby-meta-value-of-custom-field), but I find it's implementation confusing.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'kodakalaris_listing',
    'meta_key' => 'listing_region_slug',
    'meta_value' => get_microsite_slug() . '-microsite-home-featured',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'listing_index'
);
$listings = new WP_Query($args);
if ($listings->have_posts()) : while ($listings->have_posts()) : $listings->the_post();
    ?>
    ...
    ...
<?php
endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to figure this out after reading [this article](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/), but basically assigning a name to each `meta_query` array allows you to call which one should take priority when using `orderby`.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'special_listing',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'orderby' => 'index_clause',
    'meta_query' => array (
        'site_clause' => array (
            'key' => 'listing_region_slug',
            'value' => get_microsite_slug() . '-microsite-home-featured'
        ),
        'index_clause' => array (
            'key' => 'listing_index',
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to sort after you query. [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) has [`orderby` parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters):

```
function get_listings($region_slug, $count) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'special_listing',
        'meta_key' => 'listing_region_slug',
        'meta_value' => $region_slug,
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
    );
    $posts = new WP_Query($args);

    return $posts;
}
```

You'll then want to use [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) rather than a `foreach` loop, in your view.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but your answer seems to be missing a call to the `meta_key` that the `meta_value_num` should be referencing. Unless I'm way off, I dunno. Anyways, I've updated my question. Can you please take a look?

Answer (score -1):

Change the function to :

```
<?php  
// Get the first $count listings with the highest indices for a given $region_slug:
function get_listings($region_slug, $count) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'special_listing',
        'orderby'          => 'listing_index',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
        'meta_key' => 'listing_region_slug',
        'meta_value' => $region_slug
    );
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    return $posts;
}
```